# AWS CDK Gitlab CI - RuntimeError: Bundling did not produce any output. Check that content is written to /asset-output

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, aws-cdk

My CDKstack code snippet is like below,

```
class CdkLambdaInfraStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        myapp = _lambda.Function(
            self,
            "myapp",
            code=_lambda.Code.from_asset(
                get_bundle_image_path(),
                exclude=["*.pyc"],
                bundling={
                    "image": core.DockerImage.from_build(get_bundle_image_path()),
                    "command": [
                        "sh",
                        "-c",
                        f"rsync -rLv {generate_exclude_command(exclude_list)} \
                            /asset-input/ /asset-output \
                        && poetry export --with-credentials --format requirements.txt --output /asset-output/requirements.txt --without-hashes \
                        && cd /asset-output \
                        &&  python -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t /asset-output \
                        && ls -la ",

                    ],
                },
            ),
            handler="lambda_infra_cdk.compute.my_lambda.handler",
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
        )
```

And then calling it from `app.py` `cdk.json` entry point like

```
app = cdk.App()
mystack = CdkLambdaInfraStack(
    app,
    "CdkLambdaInfraStack"
)
app.synth()
```

Now my `gitlab-ci.yml` is like below.

```
stages:
  - build

# Build and push the Docker image to the GitLab image registry
# using Docker-in-Docker.
dind-build:
  stage: build

  image:
    # An alpine-based image with the `docker` CLI installed.
    name: docker:19.03

  before_script:
    # Install the `docker` CLI.
    - apk update
    - apk add gcc libc-dev libffi-dev 
    - apk add --update --no-cache python3 python3-dev && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
    - python3 -m ensurepip
    - pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools
    - pip install poetry
    - poetry install
    - source `poetry env info --path`/bin/activate

  services:
   - name: docker:dind
     alias: dockerdaemon

  variables:
    # Tell docker CLI how to talk to Docker daemon.
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://dockerdaemon:2375/
    # Use the overlayfs driver for improved performance.
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    # Disable TLS since we're running inside local network.
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: "true"

  script:
    - apk add --update nodejs npm curl
    - npm install -g aws-cdk
    - python app.py
```

Now when this CDKstack I am running in `local` its working fine, but the same in `gitlab runner` is giving me error

`RuntimeError: Bundling did not produce any output. Check that content is written to /asset-output.`

As part of `debugging` I have added the `ls -la` at the end of my `docker bundle commands` and that list all my `dependencies + lambda handler` properly.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to overcome a similar issue by changing the way bundling file access works. By default it will use [BundlingFileAccess.BIND_MOUNT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk/BundlingFileAccess.html#aws_cdk.BundlingFileAccess.BIND_MOUNT) which works fine in a normal docker situation, but not when using a shared docker socket (docker in docker). To solve that you can use [BundlingFileAccess.VOLUME_COPY](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk/BundlingFileAccess.html#aws_cdk.BundlingFileAccess.VOLUME_COPY) as it states in the description

> This is slower, but works also in more complex situations with remote or shared docker sockets.

This is because trying to mount a volume while using docker in docker with a shared socket will try to mount the host's directory and not the container running the job. Using `BundlingFileAccess.VOLUME_COPY` will create a volume and copy files instead of trying a mount. You can try it out by changing:

```py
myapp = _lambda.Function(
    self,
    "myapp",
    code=_lambda.Code.from_asset(
        get_bundle_image_path(),
        exclude=["*.pyc"],
        bundling={
            "image": core.DockerImage.from_build(get_bundle_image_path()),
            "bundling_file_access": BundlingFileAccess.VOLUME_COPY,
            "command": [
                "sh",
                "-c",
                f"rsync -rLv {generate_exclude_command(exclude_list)} \
                    /asset-input/ /asset-output \
                && poetry export --with-credentials --format requirements.txt --output /asset-output/requirements.txt --without-hashes \
                && cd /asset-output \
                &&  python -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t /asset-output \
                && ls -la ",

            ],
        },
    ),
    handler="lambda_infra_cdk.compute.my_lambda.handler",
    runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
)
```